# Scroll multiple lines with mouse in tmux

Tags: mouse, tmux, scrolling

```
setw -g mouse on
```

With that in `$HOME/.tmux.conf`, I can use the scroll wheel on my mouse to scroll tmux screen to view previous lines. But that only scrolls 1 line per mouse scroll. I want to specify a custom number like 3, which is the default in Vim (with `set mouse=a`).

I have [searched `tmux scroll multiple lines` on Google](https://google.com/search?q=tmux+scroll+multiple+lines) and found no answer. Is it possible?

I'm running **tmux 2.1** on Ubuntu 16.04 on WSL on Windows 10 v1709 Enterprise 64-bit.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36002866/configure-tmux-scroll-speed

Comment: @davidbaumann Realizing it's impossible in tmux 2.1, I cloned 2.7 from GitHub and compiled & installed it. Now I have two problems!

Comment: Stumbled across this wondering the same thing. Similar question here looks promising: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36002866/configure-tmux-scroll-speed/37370713#37370713